# Variables that are used for output data (In this case account balance) aren't changing when I call methods to alter them

Tags: java

So, for an assignment that I have, I have to create a program that will figure out when two people (John/Mary) will be able to pay back a loan that they took out and then display back how long it took them in months as well as how much they have saved over time. The program consists of 4 classes, (Application, SavingsAccount(Marys account), CurrentAccount(Johns account) and LoanAccount). I have numerous methods set to do things such as add an interest rate onto the account balance every month. Problem is it works out when the loan will be paid back, but not how much they have saved in their savings/current account while doing so. The two variables that store this information (One set to 100.0 by default, the other set to 0.0) haven't changed in value when I try to print the account value at the end. Though it will print out the LoanAccount value for each month if I want it to, which leaves me clueless to what I have done wrong.

Code below:

Application:

```
  package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author Josh
 */
public class Application {
    static private int monthJohn = 0;
    static private int monthMary = 0;
    static private float TotalDebt = 20000.00F;
    static private boolean johnFinished = false;
    static private boolean maryFinished = false;
    static private float johnTotalSaved = 0.00F;
    static private float maryTotalSaved = 0.00F;
    public static void main (String args[]){

        John();
        Mary();
        if (johnFinished == true && maryFinished == true){
            CurrentAccount amountJ = new CurrentAccount();
            float savingsJ = amountJ.getBalanceJohn();
            SavingsAccount amountM = new SavingsAccount();
            float savingsM = amountM.getBalanceSAMary();
            System.out.println("John repaid his loan after " + monthJohn + " months. His current account balance at that time was £" + savingsJ);
            System.out.println("Mary repaid her loan after " + monthMary + " months. Her savings account balance at that time was £" + savingsM);
        }


        //Test for interest rate in CA

    }
    public static void Mary(){
        LoanAccount Debt = new LoanAccount();
        float DebtPaid = Debt.getBalanceLAMary();
        while(DebtPaid <= TotalDebt){
            SavingsAccount Mary = new SavingsAccount();
            Mary.addInterestMary();
            Mary.UtilitiesMary();
            Mary.MonthlyPayMary();
            Debt.addInterestMary();
            Debt.takeLoanPaymentMary();
            DebtPaid = Debt.getBalanceLAMary();
            monthMary++;
            //System.out.println("Test: " + DebtPaid + " Month: " + monthJohn);

        }
        maryFinished = true;

    }
    public static void John(){
        float test = 0.0F;
        LoanAccount Debt = new LoanAccount();
        float DebtPaid = Debt.getBalanceLAjohn();
        while(DebtPaid <= TotalDebt){
            CurrentAccount John = new CurrentAccount();
            John.addInterestJohn();
            John.UtilitiesJohn();
            John.MonthlyPayJohn();
            Debt.addInterestJohn();
            Debt.takeLoanPaymentJohn();
            John.getBalanceJohn();
            test = John.getBalanceJohn();
            DebtPaid = Debt.getBalanceLAjohn();
            monthJohn++;
            //System.out.println("Test: " + DebtPaid + " Month: " + monthJohn + " TEST :" + test);

        }
        johnFinished = true;

        }
}
```

CurrentAccount:

```
  package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author Josh
 */
public class CurrentAccount {
    //Variable declaration
    private float balance = 0.00F;
    private float interestRate = 0.0008F;
    private float interest = 0.0F;
    private float LoanPayment = 200.00F;
    private float MonthlyWage = 2000.00F;
    private float utilitiesJohn = 1200.00F;

    public static void main (String args[]){


    }

   public float getBalanceJohn(){
       return balance;
   }
   public void addInterestJohn(){
       interest = interestRate * balance;
       balance = balance + interest;

   }
    public void MonthlyPayJohn(){
       balance = balance + MonthlyWage;

   }
   public float makeDepositJohn(){
       balance = balance - LoanPayment;
       return LoanPayment;
   }
   public void UtilitiesJohn(){
        balance = balance - utilitiesJohn;

    }
}
```

SavingsAccount:

```
  package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author Joshua Quinn-Edwards
 */
public class SavingsAccount {
    //Variable declaration
    private float balance = 100.00F;
    private float interestRate = 0.004F;
    private float interest = 0.00F;
    private float LoanPayment = 300.00F;
    private float MonthlyWage = 2000.00F;
    private float utilitiesMary = 1000.00F;

    public static void main (String args[]){

    }
    public void UtilitiesMary(){
        balance = balance - utilitiesMary;
    }
    public float getBalanceSAMary(){

       return balance;

    }
    public void addInterestMary(){
       interest = interestRate * balance;
       balance = balance + interest;
    }
   public void MonthlyPayMary(){
       balance = balance + MonthlyWage;
   }
    public float makeDepositMary(){
       balance = balance - LoanPayment;
       return LoanPayment;
    }
}
```

LoanAccount:

```
  package assignment2;

/**
 *
 * @author Josh
 */
public class LoanAccount {
    //Variables
    private float balanceJohn = 0.00F;
    private float balanceMary = 0.00F;
    private float interestRate = 0.006F;
    private float interestJohn = 0.00F;
    private float interestMary = 0.00F;


    public static void main (String args[]){

    }
    public float getBalanceLAjohn (){
        return balanceJohn;
    }
    public float getBalanceLAMary (){
        return balanceMary;
    }
    public void takeLoanPaymentJohn(){
        CurrentAccount JohnLoanPayment = new CurrentAccount();
        float Payment = JohnLoanPayment.makeDepositJohn();
        balanceJohn = balanceJohn + Payment;
    }
    void takeLoanPaymentMary(){
        SavingsAccount MaryLoanPayment = new SavingsAccount();
        float Payment = MaryLoanPayment.makeDepositMary();
        balanceMary = balanceMary + Payment;
    }

    public void addInterestMary(){
        interestMary = interestRate * balanceMary;
        balanceMary = balanceMary + interestMary;
    }
    public void addInterestJohn(){
        interestJohn = interestRate * balanceJohn;
        balanceJohn = balanceJohn + interestJohn;
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea to why I keep getting the outputs:
John repaid his loan after 79 months. His current account balance at that time was £0.0
Mary repaid her loan after 57 months. Her savings account balance at that time was £100.0

rather than the actual amounts that they would have in their accounts I would appreciate it if you could explain where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance for anyone that does give any help.

Comment: Do you really want to be creating new accounts when taking payments?

Comment: Oh wow, well after stopping it from creating a new account with every loop it's now outputting the end amount saved. Thank you for pointing that out to me. Though now I have the issue with it not getting the answer I should have.